# Angular 2 Cli application 404 Error on hard refresh

Tags: ng-build

When building using `ng build`, the build succeeds and app can be accessed.

However, when build in production mode using:

```
ng build --prod
```

It gives me an error:

> "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object".

Answer (score 0):

Add .htaccess file for apache2 and insert code in file

```
RewriteEngine on
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

and index.html file change base href

index.html

```
<base href="/angular/">
```

here angular is directory.

After that open the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf file and add the following rule on `<VirtualHost>` tag

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```